# Printing a table from a tip calculator using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to display the results from my tip calculator into a table using php, when I enter in the bill amount and tip I want it to have a table of two columns and three rows for the first column I want it to display these results-

bill amount:,tip percent: and total amount: with the results from the tip calculator to show in the other column.

I just need help starting this code off using php so that my results show in a table from what I input, here is my code that I have so far:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <form id="calculator">
     <p>Amount: <input id="amount" /></p>
  <p>Tip Percentage: <input id="percentage" /></p>
  <hr />
<p>Tip: <input id="tip" disabled="disabled" /></p>
<p>Total: <input id="total" disabled="disabled" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

  function calculate () {

   var amount = $('#amount').val();
   var percentage = $('#percentage').val();

  var tip = amount * (percentage / 100);


   var total = Number(amount) + tip;

   $('#tip').val( tip.toFixed(2) );
   $('#total').val( total.toFixed(2) );


   return false;
   }

   $('#calculator').submit( calculate );
   </script>
```

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: why are you trying to use php when you've mostly got the math down in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in comments, you can do everything with jQuery (without PHP).

```
$('#calculator').submit(function()
{
   var amount = $('#amount').val();
   var percentage = $('#percentage').val();

   // do some basic validation
   if(!$.isNumeric(amount) || amount<0 ||
      !$.isNumeric(percentage) || percentage<0)
   {
       $('#prompt').html('Please enter correct values!');
       return false;
   }

   var tip = amount * (percentage / 100);
   var total = Number(amount) + tip;

   $('#tip').html(tip.toFixed(2));
   $('#total').html(total.toFixed(2));

   return false;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aoaxe791/)

I've just added some basic validation to your input, corrected some layout (i.e. `#tip` and `#total` are results, so you can create a result table outside the form), added a prompt for displaying errors and changed `val()` to `html()` to update results. Hope it helps.